# SQLAlchemy raises an exception for unknown version while connecting to GaussDB (for openGauss)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

As the following code shows, we may choose an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) module to connect to GaussDB (for openGauss). The most popular third-party library in Python I know is SQLAlchemy. But while I connect to the openGauss through the following code, an exception for known version raises.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# ...
dsn = '{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(db_type, username, password, host, port, database)
engine = create_engine(dsn, pool_pre_ping=True)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# Base is a base class for each table.
# We want to create tables' schema, but the exception raises.
Base.metadata.create_all(
            engine,
            checkfirst=check_first
        )
```

The exception we mentioned is:

```
  File "C:\Users\wotchin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 674, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "C:\Users\wotchin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 775, in initialize
    super(PGDialect_psycopg2, self).initialize(connection)
  File "C:\Users\wotchin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\base.py", line 3182, in initialize
    super(PGDialect, self).initialize(connection)
  File "C:\Users\wotchin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 394, in initialize
    self.server_version_info = self._get_server_version_info(
  File "C:\Users\wotchin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\base.py", line 3435, in _get_server_version_info
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: Could not determine version from string '(GaussDB Kernel V500R002C00 build 434c09d8) compiled at 2021-06-26 10:18:58 commit 0 last mr 1692 debug on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by g++ (GCC) 7.3.0, 64-bit'
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem.

SQLAlchemy has a version check. Hence, we can modify the function action before using SQLAlchemy.

```py
        from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base import PGDialect
        PGDialect._get_server_version_info = lambda *args: (9, 2)
```

Comment: I have a similar situation, where I'm using a postresql variant whose version couldn't be parsed.  This was a good idea, overriding the version-check function.  I guess we'll both have to be very careful testing our code, though!

Answer (score -1):

You may try the project `opengauss-sqlalchemy` at now.

The openGauss recently provides this project to support SQLAlchemy.

Override the inner method `_get_server_version_info` of `PGDialect` could solve the problem of connecting to openGauss, but some SQLs of openGauss are different from PostgreSQL. Besides, openGauss has more reserved words than PostgreSQL, we may not notice that until we use these words as table or column name.

The project has been published on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/opengauss-sqlalchemy/)
, [gitee](https://gitee.com/opengauss/openGauss-sqlalchemy)
and [github](https://github.com/opengauss-mirror/openGauss-sqlalchemy)